# feed reader using nsxmlparserdelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, rss, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

i am creating an app that shows the latest feeds from a particular webservice,i am using NSXMLParserDelegate protocol for this purpose,well i read the apple documentation and i tried some tutorials too,but something seems to be going wrong somewhere,i dont understand how does the didEndElement,foundCharacters work,anyways i want to display the image,title and content,pub-date of the post,i am newbie to xmlparsing here's my **viewcontroller.h**(i have just parsed only the title element in the following code)

```
   @property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *currentElement;
   @property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *currentTitle;
   @property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *titles;
```

**viewdidload**

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.forbes.com/fast/feed"];
NSXMLParser *parser=[[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
[parser setDelegate:self];
[parser parse];
NSLog(@"%d",titles.count);
```

**didStartElement**

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
 {

self.currentElement=elementName;

if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) 
{

    self.currentTitle=[NSMutableString alloc];
    titles=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    titles=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"title"];
}
 }
```

**foundCharacters**

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
 {

self.currentElement=elementName;

if ([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) 
{

    self.currentTitle=[NSMutableString alloc];
    titles=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    titles=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"title"];
}
  }
```

**didEndElement**

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
if([self.currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"])
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.currentTitle);


}
}
```

***doubts***

**1)where am i supposed to declare my titles array so that i can add individual title object to it.
what is the use of [attributeDict objectForKey] in didStartElement? it returned null for my program**

**2)what does foundCharacters delegate actually do? what does it append?**

**3)After didEndElement why doesnt the compiler reach for didStartElement and not the foundCharacters ?**

**4)finally should i actually use NSXMLParserDelegate protocol for the xml parsing,do others like touchXML,TBXML and others provided in the raywenderlich make a difference?**

i am sorry for the long post,but i havent got any satisfying answers online regarding my queries,i used all the breakpoints and figured out how the delegates are called back and forth,i need some enlightening answers to my queries,thanks and sorry

Comment: Why not just use [RSSKit](http://github.com/H2CO3/RSSKit)?

Comment: @H2CO3 how am i supposed to use your RSSKit? am i supposed to drag all the files into my project? apart from the explanation given on github,is there any other information i can find online? thanks

Comment: yes, just add the files to your project. I don't know about any other documentation, but what is written on GitHub should be enough. You have to really just implement that one delegate method and that's it. Please note also that RSSKit doesn't support ARC, so you should turn ARC off for all the RSSKit files.

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry to bother you again,but even after adding the files to the project it gives a lexical or preprocessor issue,i cant seem to get those files working,am i supposed to change the project settings or something?

Comment: you provided no information about what the issue is and my crystal ball is broken, so the best advice I can give you is to have a look at the files, the includes, understand what does what and organize them and/or add compiler flags accordingly. You **are supposed** to be able to resolve such an "issue".

Comment: @H2CO3 'RSSKit/RSSKit.h' file not found,can you please fix your crystal ball now? and i have gone through the code inside each file,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Declare your array before starting to parse.Whenever you meet an elements (an xml tag), initialize the elements (set some BOOL in the class in a way that you can recognize what element you are reading);

**2.** Found characters are the characters found as value of a tag.If you know what element you are reading (reading your instance variables), you should append this string to your temporary NSMutableString and add it to the array only when the element is ended.

**3.** Because it doesn't start finding other characters until a new tag is reached.

**Example**

I see that you are confused,  let's say that you have this XML code:

```
<person> mickey mouse </person>
```

When you meet the tag  the element starts, then you find other characters (not the entire string, just a part of the string) until the string ends, then when you meet the  tag the element is ended.

Answer (score 0):

in didFindCharacters just add the found characters to a NSMutableString and in didEndElement you know what you ended and set a variable to the strings you found

image:
image => the character at didEnd are the name of the link, the url is in the attributes past in didStart

title-tag
didStart => didStart : html started, every tag is html until the didEnd of title-tag

content:
didStart => didStart : html started, every tag is html until the didEnd of content